# xmlserialize, xmlagg, xmltext used in the Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a task is change the DB2 sql to Postgres sql. It has a problem in XML handle.

I tried to used this sql

```
SELECT xmlagg( ', <foo>abc</foo>')   as YM 
FROM TEST_Table"
```

It's working fine.

But

```
SELECT  xmlagg( concat(', ', TRIM(CATEGORY)))  as YM 
from TEST_Table
```

is not working.

> Error msg : SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function xmlagg(text) does not exist
>     Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

My question is how to change the below DB2sql to Postgres sql ?

```
**SELECT substr( xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', TRIM(NM_TEXT) ) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) ), 3, 128 ) as YM 
FROM TEST_Table**
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you trying to create a comma separated list of values? Then use `string_agg(nm_text, ',')` to do that. No need for XML aggregation